# Solutions to $(y^{'})^{2}+y^{2}-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Been looking for solutions to the following ODE,

$(y^{'})^{2}+y^{2}-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}=0$

Does anyone have  clue how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}-y^2}}$$

which has no close form for the integration.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$t(x)=\sqrt{1+y^2}.$$
Then
$$y^2=t^2-1,$$
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2.$$
Finally,
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}(1+t-t^2)}.$$